# Why does NEW.name return NULL? PostgreSQL 11

Tags: postgresql, triggers, database-partitioning

I wrote a function that should automatically create new partitions for the table. I created a trigger, but when the trigger fires and the function is called, nothing happens, just an error appears:

```
ERROR: query string argument of EXECUTE is null
```

Function code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.auto_part()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF 
AS $BODY$DECLARE
    partition_date TEXT;
    partition TEXT;
    startdate TEXT;
    enddate TEXT;
    query TEXT;
BEGIN
    partition_date := TO_CHAR(new.created_on,'YYYY-MM');
    startdate := partition_date || '-01';
    enddate := to_char(to_timestamp('YYYY-MM',partition_date) + '1 MONTH'::interval,'YYYY-MM') || '-01';
    
    partition := TG_TABLE_NAME || '_' || partition_date;
    
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname=partition) THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'TABLE %',TG_TABLE_NAME;
        RAISE NOTICE 'ID %',new.id;
        RAISE NOTICE 'NAME %',new.username;
        RAISE NOTICE 'CREATED_ON %',new.created_on;
        RAISE NOTICE 'PARTITION_DATE %',partition_date;
        RAISE NOTICE 'STARTDATE %',startdate;
        RAISE NOTICE 'A partition has been created %',partition;
        EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || partition || ' PARTITION OF ' || TG_TABLE_NAME || ' FOR VALUES FROM ('|| startdate || ') TO (' || enddate || ');';
        --RAISE NOTICE query;
        --EXECUTE query;
        RETURN 1;
    END IF;
END
$BODY$;
```

Conclusion "RAISE NOTICE":

```
NOTICE:  TABLE users_sec
NOTICE:  ID <NULL>
NOTICE:  NAME <NULL>
NOTICE:  CREATED_ON <NULL>
NOTICE:  PARTITION_DATE <NULL>
NOTICE:  STARTDATE <NULL>
NOTICE:  A partition has been created <NULL>

ERROR:  query string argument of EXECUTE is null
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function auto_part() line 22 at EXECUTE
SQL state: 22004
```

Trigger code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER auto_part_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
    ON public.users_sec
    FOR EACH STATEMENT
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.auto_part();
```

Insert example:

```
INSERT INTO users_sec(
    username, password, created_on, last_logged_on)
    VALUES (
        'qwerty',
        random_string( 20 ),
        '2021-03-23',
        '2021-03-24'
    );
```

Table creation code:

```
CREATE TABLE public.users_sec
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('users_sec_id_seq'::regclass) ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    username text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    password text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    created_on timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    last_logged_on timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT users_sec_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, created_on)
) PARTITION BY RANGE (created_on) 
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `NEW` to contain the row about to be inserted, you have to use a `FOR EACH ROW` level trigger.

Since [you cannot have a `BEFORE` trigger `FOR EACH ROW` on a partitioned table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE-LIMITATIONS), that's kind of a catch 22 situiation.

A possible way our may be this:

- Create a `DEFAULT` partition. All rows that don't match an existing partition will be inserted there.
- Define a `BEFORE` trigger `FOR EACH ROW` *on the default partition*. The trigger creates a new partition as appropriate and inserts the row into that partition. The trigger function uses `RETURN NULL` to avoid inserting anything in the default partition itself.

This way, the default partition remains empty. Moreover, you only have to pay the overhead for a trigger for rows that don't go in any of the existing partitions!

Comment: I have reworked the answer. Apologies for not grasping immediately that this was about a partitioned table.